If $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible (over $\mathbb{Q}$), is it always possible to find $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ with $f(ax+b)$ Eisenstein?
My initial thought is no, simply because it seems too easy if it is true.
The simplest example of a nontrivial irreducible polynomial I could think of was $f(x)=x^2+1$. Unfortunately, $f(x+1)$ is Eisenstein at $p=2$.
Then I considered $f(x)=x^2+4$, skipping $2$ and $3$ as those are Eisenstein, and I believe I have a proof.
If $f(ax+b)=a^2x^2+2abx+(b^2+4)$ is Eisenstein at $p$ (where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$), then $p\nmid a^2$ so $p\nmid a$ and thus (as $p \mid 2ab$), we must have $p \mid 2b$.
If $p=2$, then $b$ must be even as $2\mid (b^2+4)$. But then $b^2$ is divisble by $4$ so $2^2 \mid b^2+4$, which contradicts Eisenstein's criterion.
If $p$ is odd, then $p\mid b$, so clearly we have $p\mid b^2$. As $p\mid b^2+4$, we must have $p\mid 4$, which is a contradiction.
So no $a$ and $b$ exist.
My question is: is it sufficient to show that no integer $a$ and $b$ exist?

@lulu So the answer to my title is indeed no, however this does not help understand if my proof is correct.

To check that your proof works for rational numbers as well, you may just look at $f((mx+n)/k)$ where $m,n,k$ are integers. After factoring out $1/k^2$, this becomes $$m^2x^2+2mnx+(n^2+4k^2).$$ So you could fall back on your original proof by considering $a=m$ and $b=n$, and then the only difference is that the constant $4$ is now $4k^2$.
The one place where this difference affects your proof is in the case where $p$ is odd and you would then deduce that $p\mid 4k^2$. It follows that $p\mid k$, and you know that $p\mid n$, so now $p^2\mid (n^2+4k^2)$, contradicting Eisenstein.
